# custom background button missing text

Tags: android, button

Currently I am trying to create custom button with custom background, the point is that I want to create rounded edge for the button programmatically. This is the code that I create:

```
GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, new int[] {Color.parseColor("#ffffff"),Color.parseColor("#999999")});
gd.setCornerRadii(new float[] { 0, 0, 10, 10, 10, 10, 0, 0 });
gd.setStroke(1, Color.parseColor("#33364252"));

Button pillButtonRight = new Button(this);
pillButtonRight.setId(R.id.pillButtonRight);
pillButtonRight.setBackgroundDrawable(gd);  
pillButtonRight.setWidth(ViewUtils.getScreenWidth(getBaseContext())/8);
pillButtonRight.setHeight(ViewUtils.getScreenHeight(getBaseContext())/40);
pillButtonRight.setText("English");     
pillButtonRight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
pillButtonRight.setTextSize(12);
```

The code behind getscreenwidth and getscreenheight is

```
WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) ctx.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
int screenWidthDp = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, display.getWidth(), ctx.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

The result is the text is gone

Is there any work around on this?

Answer (score 0):

change color of your text

```
pillButtonRight.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff00ff00"));
```

Comment: This has been solved, I notice that this is because of the size of the text and the height.